# Add scrollbar in undecorated JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

I am using a `JFrame` in a java application and I needed to have it undecorated, so I just set `setUndecorated(true)`. I am using 3 panels in frame. Top, left and right. All frames have `setLayout(null)`.

Now I want to add scroll bar in right panel. I tried every thing available but I can't get it. Is there any way that I can have scroll bar?

Comment: *"All frames have setLayout(null)"* and now you're screwed. *"Is there any way that I can have scroll bar?"* - Yes, use a `JScrollPane`, that's what it's therefore...however, `setLayout(null)` is going to screw that up...

Comment: Post code for an undecorated `JFrame` and 3 `JPanel`s with one of them in a `JScrollPane` if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) for that purpose.

It is a container that automatically provides scroll-bar if the contents exceed it's size.

---

Secondly, using `setLayout(null)` is a bad practice. Actually it is worse than a bad practice. You should avoid with all efforts you can muster.

**Try using suitable `LayoutManager`.**

Here is a [nice tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for using them.
You can also have a look at [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks guys for answers. However, I know that setLayout(null) is not the best way of programming, but this problem also occurs in borderLayout. Plus for the application, it's necessary. And JScrollPane was the first thing I tried, didn't work.

Comment: I don't suppose it's a problem with `JScrollPane` or layout managers, they are part of JDK, well tested and work well for thousands of people. There might be something small missing in the way you are using them. I think posting the code would be the only way people might help you.